# How to use OR operator on interable where?

Tags: flutter, dart

I implement search bar. User can search either `categoryName` or `categoryId`. I tried this way, but not working.

(This one like `AND operator`. Isn't it?)
I want to `OR operator`

```
final result = jobProvider.where((a) => a.categoryName.toLowerCase().contains(query))
.where((b) => b.categoryId.toLowerCase().contains(query));
```

Comment: what's the error ? why don't you use jobProvider.where((a) => a.categoryName.toLowerCase().contains(query) || a.categoryId.toLowerCase().contains(query) )

Comment: For OR use ||, for AND use &&

Comment: Edit history: I moved your answer, which was merged into the question, into a separate wiki answer, and it was deleted by a moderator (which may be a good call). Feel free to add your own answer if it was sufficiently different from the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `||` in your condition :

```
final result = jobProvider.where((a) => a.categoryName.toLowerCase().contains(query) || a.categoryId.toLowerCase().contains(query));
```